# Font-size in px and in rem: Why add both to the same element?

Tags: css, font-size

```
body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  color: #404040;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5; }
```

What does that mean and how does it work?

Comment: For browsers that don't support REM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`px` here is a fallback for browsers which do not support the `rem` unit (IE8 is a notable example).

Check out the [`rem` Can I Use... feature](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem) for browser support.

Any browser which does not support the `rem` unit will instead rely on the `px` unit, preventing the browser from defaulting the font size to whatever it pleases.

Answer (score 2):

`font-size`in pixels will be the the falback for [`rem`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem) when browsers won't support it.

In this case will be **IE8**, or **IE9/10**, if using `font` shorthand property

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is a fallback.

It's also important to note order is important, and if the two declarations were reversed, it would serve no purpose.

The css declaration sets a font size of 16px, then attempts to override that with 1 rem.
If the browser does not support rem, that override will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

When one of unit doesn't work it will use the one which will be default...but if you write as you have written in code and both is allowed it will select the one  which is been latest according to rule of **Specificity** in CSS.